# How to compute the initial matrix from result

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

By multiplying the below matrix element wise, we can find the answer as $A.B = C$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    7 \\
    18 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there any way to to find B (2x2 matrix) if we know C and A?

Comment: The multiplication on the LHS is not defined: did you mean to have the 2x2 matrix on the left multiplying the 2x1 vector?

Comment: In general, we can't. Take $A=C=0$. Then any $B$ is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but you won't get a unique matrix $B$. Namely, if:

$$B=\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right]$$

then your equation for $B$ looks like this:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}2\\3\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}7\\18\end{matrix}\right]$$

which is equivalent to the following system of equations:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}2a+3b&=&7\\2c+3d&=&18\end{array}$$

which doesn't have a unique solution. For example, you can freely choose $a$ and $c$, and set $b=\frac{1}{3}(7-2a)$ and $d=\frac{1}{3}(18-2c)$, so:

$$B=\left[\begin{matrix}a&\frac{1}{3}(7-2a)\\c&\frac{1}{3}(18-2c)\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0&7/3\\0&6\end{matrix}\right]+a\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2/3\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]+c\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&-2/3\end{matrix}\right]$$

for any numbers $a,c$.